# Getting error after updating the android studio into Android L Developer Preview?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop

Error:Execution failed for task ':Wallpaperapp:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version L declared in library com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probabaly your project uses using dynamic versions such as

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
```

or

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:latest.integration'
```

and with the latest updates (releases) these points to L-preview support library (v21). L-preview support library currently have minSdkVersion L therefore if you want to include L-preview support library, your minSdkVersion should be set to L.

To maintain your minSdkVersion and use support library you should no use dynamic version and use older version of the library ( < v21).

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
```

or

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
```

Note: if you want to use or try v21 support library on older versions this link explains a workaround: http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/297xli/howto_use_the_v21_support_libs_on_older_versions/

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:BUILD_TOOL VERSION'

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because my app is set to: `minSdkVersion 14`.  To alleviate that problem add the following to your AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.domain.appname"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        tools:node="replace" />
```

I hear its a bug with the latest Android L SDK...essentially this forces AS to refer to the `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` set in your build.gradle file